# Fitting a normalized histogram using gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

I have a datafile containing N random numbers generated from a C-code. Now I want to normalize the histogram from this datafile and, then, fit it to a given distribution function. How can I do that?
This is my gnuplot code for the histogram plot:

```
width = 5000
hist(x,width)=width*floor(x/width)+width/2.0
set boxwidth width
set style fill solid 0.5
set xrange [0:500000]
set yrange [0:20]
plot "out.dat" u (hist($1,width)):(1.0) smooth freq w boxes lc rgb"green"
```

Answer (score 2):

Since gnuplot version 5.2 there is an new smoothing type `smooth fnormal` which does exactly that: sum up all values with same x-value and normalize the data so that the overall sum is 1.

A simple example:

```
set boxwidth 0.9
set style fill solid 0.5
set yrange [0:*]

$data <<EOD
1
1
2
2
2
3
3
EOD
set style data boxes
plot $data u 1:(1) smooth freq title 'smooth frequency',\
     '' u 1:(1) smooth fnormal title 'smooth fnormal'
```

[image]

Applied to you example you must only update the actual plotting line to

```
plot "out.dat" u (hist($1,width)):(1.0/(sum)) smooth fnormal w boxes lc rgb "green"
```

Comment: Thank you. I've upgraded my ubuntu to verson 5.2.2 and it works. But then, how to fit this normalized histogram to a given distribution?